# How to find origin url from within ASP.NET Web Service Controller Action

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a .NET webservice where I want to apply some logic based on the origin of a get request.

I'm a little confused on where that property would be found.

I want to do something like this:

```
    [OverrideAuthorization]
    [HttpGet]
    public List<My_Object> CollectData()
    {
        if(Request.origin == "https://stackoverflow.com")
        {
          . . . Do something
        }
        else
        {
          . . . Do something else
        }


        . . .More Code


        return List<My_Object>;
    }
```

I'm just confused about what needs to go in place of "Request.origin" above.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, maybe because I'm trying to look for properties while I'm making calls from localhost?

**Thank you in advance for any help.**

Comment: I think you might be refering to `Request.Headers.GetValues("Origin");`

Comment: I thought about this, but I don't see an Origin header when I make a request from Firefox. Do local requests not have an origin header maybe?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check for [HttpRequest.UrlReferrer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer?view=netframework-4.7.2).

This value would be set by client to indicatae the page from which this request was originated.

You should be able to get it using below code:

```
string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems like what I need, but how would I reference the request that was sent to the controller? The only object I know I have reference to is Request, and that is an HttpRequestMessage object.

Comment: added sample code on how to get referrer.  hope it brings more clarity in the answer..

Comment: I couldn't use an index to access that header, but I am now using Request.Headers.Referrer.ToString(). That statement returns null though.

Comment: Did you try Request.UrlReferrer ?  If not, then please try it.  Also you can check in fiddler if this header is being sent by your client.  This header is set by client browser and hence sometimes it may be null.

Comment: Request.UrlReferrer is not recognized by intellisense. I can purposefully send a header called "Referrer" through my HttpClient, but I was just trying to make sure that a request from my browser would send it.

Comment: It's incorrect to use Referrer in this case. Client can send any referrer to server.